# Use a Yandex-tank with a custom protocol

Tags: load-testing, yandex-tank

I want to use the Yandex tank to test a service available via a special protocol (no HTTP).

Is it possible? I could not find examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yandex tank per se is not a load testing tool, it's a wrapper which can use a "real" load testing tool for conducting the load.

The tools which are supported are:

- [phantom](https://github.com/mamchits/phantom)
- [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/)
- [bfg](https://pypi.org/project/bfg/)

So if none of this load generators supports your "special" protocol you cannot use it for load testing of your service.

If you like wrappers more than real load testing tools you might also be interested in [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation/) which is more advanced, supports [more load testing tools](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Index/) and has better [configuration syntax](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/).